# Preparing training data for NLP machine learning task

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, word-embeddings, nlp

I have the natural language sentences as follows:

`This is a black chair. It is next to the table.`

Each phrase that represents an object is annotated with an object Id. For example, in the above sentence, we have:

`This: 15, black chair: 15, It: 15, table: 14`

(where, 14 and 15 are object Ids)

I would like to train a model to predict the object Id of each phrase representing an object for a new sentence. From what I understand, each training example will consist of the following structure:

`Inputs:` sentence + object phrase

`Output:` object id (from 18 available ids)

I would need to repeat the above for each object phrase in a sentence

My question: How do I prepare the training data for this task? How do I represent each object phrase (eg: 'black chair') and each sentence for training the neural network?

Answer (score 0):

Nlp like spacy remove stop works and identify proper nouns and nouns.  It does fairly well at identifying nouns but is not perfect.  Try a sample of your data and see how accurate your percentages become.  Use the medium model

Comment: Post a paragraph and I will run it through some code and I will post back the results

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm able to extract noun chunks for the sentences. My question is how do I convert this data into vectors so that I can train a classifier?

Comment: Use count vectorizor or tfidf tokenizers